# Adding between two dates sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that gets the sum between two dates but that's only if they have the same year.

```
SELECT 
    [Purchased Product], 
    SUM(CONVERT(INT, [Purchased Quantity])) AS [Quantity]  
FROM 
    StudentPurchasedHistoryTable 
WHERE 
    DATENAME(month, [Purchased Date]) BETWEEN 'july' AND 'may' 
GROUP BY 
    [Purchased Product]
```

How do I get the sum between two dates but now it came from last year month?

For example between July this year and May last year.

Comment: why are you doing `DATENAME`, why not just use the date between two dates, you can build the two dates if required.

Comment: @AD.Net when i used the dates it only combines dates with the same dates, what i want to do is to combine all of them

Comment: you can still use `between` two date variables, it'll work

Comment: @AD.Net how will i do it ? i only want to get the month and the year of the dates

Comment: added `sql-server` based on the used (non-standard) syntax

Comment: You want to include all of the months with names that are alphabetically between July and May, e.g. June and March?

Answer (score 2):

You can declare 2 variables and change it based on your needs, so you get the expected query results. Or explicitly hard-code them in your `where` clause. It is also a suggested you not use `datename`. Use `datepart()` instead.

```
declare @startdate date = '20140501';
declare @enddate date = '20150731';

SELECT [Purchased Product], sum(CONVERT(INT,[Purchased Quantity])) as [Quantity]  
From StudentPurchasedHistoryTable 
WHERE [Purchased Date] between @startdate and @enddate
Group By [Purchased Product]
```